# iOS Memory Managed differently when Debugging

Tags: objective-c, ipad, debugging, memory-management

I am experiencing some odd behaviour - I have a property "key" being released in an object's dealloc, this works fine when I am debugging the app on my iPad.

But, when I launch the app "normally" i.e. without running it via XCode, it crashes immediately and from looking at the crash log, I can see it's because the "key" property is throwing an BAD ACCESS error where it is being released.

Does anyone know why my app might behave differently in these two scenarios?

I can obviously fix the bug, but I am not sure even why it is happening...

Comment: An `release` doesn't necessary release the object at once. I.e. when you use the debugger it might still exist but flagged for removal. And when you run it it is removed already.

Comment: so you're saying when the app is running "normally" it might be getting removed from memory quicker?

Comment: That's my experience of objective C, yes. Since it isn't obvious when the memory management is ran. I've had the same problem as you and it always boils down to erroneous retain/release in my cases :)

Comment: ok - i will see if i can track this down. thanks for your help!